# (RoR)how to Integer convert to data by DataTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5

would you like tell me how to use DateTime method
you may have notice,I'm not fluently English because of i'm Japanese
i try writing question in English, and sorry if you are suffer from reading my English!!

i want to convert from integer to Data.i can convert from string to data, but i can convert from integer to data.

ex(using my controller):

```
def time_from_excel_date_time(excel_date)
   if excel_date.is_a?(String) || excel_date.is_a?(Date)
    date = excel_date.in_time_zone 
   elsif excel_date.is_a?(Integer)
     other_date = DateTime.new(excel_date).in_time_zone 
     date = other_date.in_time_zone
   else 
     return nil
   end

  date
end
```

```
=> excel_date
=> 44235
>> DateTime.new(44235).in_time_zone
=> Thu, 01 Jan 44235 09:00:00 JST +09:00
```

config/application

```
config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
config.i18n.available_locales = %i[ja en]
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_types = [:datetime]
config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

i want to gain like a bottom shape

```
date = "???/???/???"
```

which do I?

> change from (=> Thu, 01 Jan 44235 09:00:00 JST +09:00) used DateTime.new()method to ("???/???/???") by other method?

or

> change from (excel_date) to ("???/???/???") by other method except method of DateTime.new()?

i try to both skill of programing and english!!

thank you for reading!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Time.at(i)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-c-at) to create a `Time`, and you could use [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) to format `Time`.

```rb
time = Time.at(44235)     # => 1970-01-01 20:17:15 +0800

time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") # => "1970/01/01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Excel are "number of days after 31/12/1899" (the integer part) plus a fraction of day. The number `34567.89` represents 34567 days after the start of 20th century, plus around 21 hours and  22 minutes.

The simplest option is to have your "starting point" (31/12/1899 at midnight) converted to unix time (`-2209078800`), then add your number multiplied by 86400 (the number of seconds in a day), and finally convert to date:

```rb
EXCEL_EPOCH = -2_209_078_800
TICKS_PER_DAY = 60 * 60 * 24

def time_from_excel_date_time(excel_date)
  # when it is a number like 44235
  unix_timestamp = excel_date * TICKS_PER_DAY + EXCEL_EPOCH
  Time.at(unix_timestamp).to_datetime
end
```

---

To be clearer:

- Excel gives you the number of days since 31/12/1899 (with decimals)
- By multiplying by `TICKS_PER_DAY` you get the number of seconds since 31/12/1899.
- By subtracting `2_209_078_800` you get the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 (which is the "zero" time in most programming languages).
- You then pass the resulting number to `Time.at` to obtain an instance of `Time`. If you need an instance of DateTime, you can convert using `.to_datetime`.

I hope this is clear enough :)

Comment: thanks you for answer my question despite of my english isn't fluently   I effort to understand which you write. Method of "Time.at (). to_datetime" is can use when i know had passed how much seconds from "31/12/1899", right?So, "excel_date * TICKS_PER_DAY + EXCEL_EPOCH" can calucurate secounds how much passed from "31/12/1899", right? Would you tell me your answer!

Comment: I'll clarify in the original answer.

Comment: thanks you so much for you answer detailing, i try it !